# Neural net classifier outputting extreme probabilities

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, classification, nlp

I am training a multi-label neural network text classifier (i.e. a given sample can have more than one label; most samples have exactly 1 label though):

1. Single-layer BiLSTM producing a sequence of (16, 512) vectors with dropout of 0.2
2. Self attention over each output vector of LSTM to produce a single 512-dimension "sentence vector"
3. L2 normalize sentence vector
4. ReLU layer on the normalized vector with about 750 units
5. Dropout of 0.3
6. Final sigmoid output layer to output a probability for each of the K classes (K~1000)

Firstly, does L2 normalization help or make things worse?

Secondly, this model is quite accurate but outputs very extreme "probabilities" for each class for the samples - very often < 0.00001 or > 0.9999 probability, instead of something less extreme (like say 0.8 or 0.2 or whatever). Any idea of what might be going wrong? If this is overfitting -- I'm using quite a bit of dropout too but that didn't help either. How can I remedy this?

Comment: If the accuracy is high (on test data?) but probabilities are extreme, it could just be that the problem is easy; the network will push log-odds to $\pm\infty$.  I believe that regularization may reduce this (large log-odds coming from large coefficients).

Comment: Thanks for the response @BenReiniger. The accuracy is high but the mistakes are also quite high-confidence; can it be because of a learning rate that's too high?

Comment: Are the high-confidence mistakes in the training set, or test (or both)?  Those could be outliers/mislabeled.  Are the coefficients large?  I would certainly start with some regularization.  If there are relatively few of these high-confidence mistakes, that might still be the optimum loss, but penalizing large coefficients should pull things back a bit.